# Qué representan estos caracteres en fscanf?

Tags: c

Buena estaba programando y un amigo me mando un codigo en el que se encuentra

```
fscanf(fid," %[^\t] %[^\t]\t%f\t%[^\n] ",DNI,Nombre,&Watts,Linea);
```

Me gustaria saber que son esos caracteres (%[^\t] %[^\t]\t%f\t%[^\n) y para que sirven en la funcion fscanf, segun tengo entendido \t y \n es tabulador y salto de linea respectivamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%[^\t]
```

Esto le indica a `fscanf` que debe leer todo hasta el primer tabulador, que no se incluirá en dicha lectura. Algo parecido sucede con la última lectura:

```
%[^\n]
```

En este caso la lectura no finaliza hasta que no se encuentre con un salto de línea.